# msbuild TransformWebConfig task - doesn't work for App.configs?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, slowcheetah

I have a windows service that will need to have the same kind of transformations that the web.configs would use, but VS 2010 doesn't seem to support that.  I've tried manually adding the App.Release.Config files, and then using msbuil [PROJ] /T:TransformWebConfig /p:Configuration=Release but no transformation is performed.  I got a TransformWebConfig folder createed in my obj subdirectory, but that's it.

Is this thing hardcoded to only work with web.configs?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the TransformWebConfig task is designed to work on web.config
(File: *$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets* Line: 199)

But you could make it work by :

1. Setting the **Build Action** of your App.config file to **Content**
2. Setting the value of **ProjectConfigFileName** to **App.config** :

> msbuild $ProjectFile$ /t:TransformWebConfig /p:ProjectConfigFileName=App.config;Configuration=Release

Comment: the work around did not work for me? error MSB4057: The target "TransformWebConfig" does not exist in the project.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and came across an article that details how to accomplish transforming app.config files:

http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.com/2010/05/applying-xdt-magic-to-appconfig.html

I walked through the steps and was successfully able to transform my app.config file.

Answer (score 1):

You can now use a plugin called [SlowCheetah](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5) to transform not only app.configs but any xml files using the same transformation engine